# Compiling libevent on Windows server?

Tags: windows, source

it would be immensly helpful if someone could indicate me how to compile libevent http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/ on Windows 7.

I usually use compile source code on Linux distributions, as executable binaries are usually always available for Windows.

---

Help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that this is a really old question but I'll shoot you an answer anyway.

If you have Visual Studio installed, open the Visual Studio Command Prompt for your architecture (usually in a "Tools" directory). cd to the directory in which you've extracted the libevent source and then type 
    nmake Makefile.nmake

That will give you the .lib and .obj files that you need.